# Creating a promise for rendering templates in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to create a function for rendering views in NodeJS that will be called using `await` later on.

```
const getTemplate = async (template, context) => {
  app.render(template, { data: context }, (error, html) => {
    return html;
  });
}

const data = require('./data.json');

app.get('/pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const html = await getTemplate('invoice', data);
  res.send(html);
});
```

Right now it gives me an empty response and that's probably because it exits the `getTemplate` function before the render callback fires, but i don't know how to modify it in an elegant way.

Comment: You never return anything from getTemplate. You must promisify app.render or build a promise yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a promise from `getTemplate`. Since you want to wait for the `app.render` to finish, I hope the following code does what you intend to do :)

```
// `async` is not really necessary as you are not using `await`, but you may provide it, if you want
const getTemplate = /* async */ (template, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.render(template, { data: context }, (error, html) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(html);
    });
  });
}

const data = require('./data.json');

app.get('/pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const html = await getTemplate('invoice', data);
  res.send(html);
});
```

Comment: Not that it's wrong but I tend to prefer `if (error) reject(error); else resolve(html);` to emphasize that the callback doesn't really use a `return` value, since it's ignored.